# Logic to access levels

Tags: php, logic

I got the idea down, and to be so simple, I think it may be impractical, and so I would comment on the pros (if any) and cons of such a system.

The intention was to develop a simple but functional system permissions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Reminds me of aspect oriented programming. You could write a reflection wrapper that inspects the doc blocks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I could see is that if you want to protect a particular function, you have to suddenly rename it to have the `conf_` prefix.

I would write a proxy around a class that inspects the doc blocks when a method is invoked. Just an idea:

```
class ArticlesProxy
{
    private $backend;

    public function __construct(articles $backend)
    {
        $this->backend = $backend;
    }

    public function __call($fn, $args)
    {
        $rm = new ReflectionMethod($this->backend, $fn);
        if (strpos($rm->getDocComment(), 'protected') !== false) {
            // this method is protected by whatever
        }
        // perform the proxy call
        return $rm->invokeArgs($args);
    }
}

$proxy = new ArticlesProxy(new articles());
$proxy->create(1, 2, 3);
```